# Caching GitHub Action Docker Container

Tags: docker, caching, github-actions

In my GitHub action, I want to run things inside a specific container. I know I can do this with the `container:` option. However, this will pull a fresh image every time I run and that takes a lot of time. Is there a way for me to cache this image that is used by `container:` so my action runs faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using self-hosted or github hosted runner?

Comment: GitHub hosted runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you're using GitHub hosted runners, I don't see any way you could do Docker caching, at least at this point in time. This is because each time your workflow runs you get a different runner.